# How to write NSString to the NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsview

I can write to iOS using something similar(UI instead of NS).  But fails for OSX?

```
NSString *sText = @"Hello";
[sText drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 150, 20) withFont:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fSize]]; 
// No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'drawInRect:withFont:'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSAttributedString` properties on OS X:

```
NSString *sText = @"Hello";
[sText drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 150, 20) withAttributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName : 
                                             [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fSize] }];
```

↳ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/index.html

Comment: Aren't downvoting bastards that give no explanation great?

Comment: Agreed.  Upvoting to compensate for the arbitrary downvote.  Your answer looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: using "drawAtPoint":

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/drawing-text-to-an-nsview.904433/